# ImageView onlongclick called twice for a medium length press

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an imageview that calls a fullscreen image viewer activity when the imageview receives a longclick. The code and the imageview's xml declaration are below. If the image is pressed and held, the image viewer activity is started as I expect, and if the image is clicked briefly it does nothing, also as I expect. However, if I press the image and then release it after a brief pause, the fullscreen image viewer activity gets opened twice. Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
        try {
            // get input stream
            String path = "MyData/MyImages/" + myClass.getRESOURCE();
            ins = getAssets().open(path);
            // load image as Drawable
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ins, null);
            // set image to ImageView
            theImage.setImageDrawable(d);
            theImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            theImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                //@Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(startActivity.this, MultiTouchActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("whoops", ""+ex);
            }
        finally {
            //close input
            if (ins != null) {
                try {
                    ins.close();
                    }
                catch (IOException ioex) {
                    //Very bad things just happened... handle it
                    }
                }
            }
        }

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/square"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: can you try returning false ontouch event of the imageview?

Comment: why comment out the overide?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However, changing the value returned to false and using @override did not solve the issue. I think I will just implement an OnClickListener and be done with it.